# Turtle does not draw anything

Tags: tikz-pgf

Tried using Turtle example from Tikz manual but it did not output any graphics that I could see. Below MWE produces blank white page. What am I doing wrong? Is my Texlive install broken?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikz[turtle/distance=1cm]
        \draw [thick,red,turtle={home,forward,right,forward,left,forward,left,forward}];

        \tikz \filldraw [thick,blue,fill=blue!20][turtle=home]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        {
            [turtle={forward,right=144}]
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This certainly does produce some graphics, as evident from the compilation log when specifying overly large distance (30cm for example). But the result is not visible in PDF.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) don't use `figure` inside `standalone` class, 2) don't nest TikZ stuff, namely `\tikz` inside `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: I switched to standalone after seeing this problem inside regular article class. I'll edit MWE to avoid confusion. As to 2) I was simply following the manual expecting the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two wrong things:

1. Don't use `standalone` class when you want `figure` environment.
2. No need to use `\tikz` environment inside `tikzpicture` environment.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[turtle/distance=1cm]
        \draw [thick,red,turtle={home,forward,right,forward,left,forward,left,forward}];

        \filldraw [thick,blue,fill=blue!20][turtle=home]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        {
            [turtle={forward,right=144}]
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `standalone` class, you may take shelter under `scope`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[turtle/distance=1cm]
        \draw [thick,red,turtle={home,forward,right,forward,left,forward,left,forward}];
        \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
        \filldraw [thick,blue,fill=blue!20][turtle=home]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        {
            [turtle={forward,right=144}]
        };
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the first point. Why discourage the use of the beautiful (and useful) standalone? Here the problem was clearly the use of `figure` along with `tikz` class option and nesting TikZ elements. Of course, removing `figure` and using two `tikzpicture`s will work in `standalone`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino May be I wasn't clear enough. I edited. That comment was for the use of figure with standalone.

Comment: no problem at all :) Perhaps you can show an example with `standalone` class: this would make your answer great.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Your wish is my command :) Done.

Comment: When the manual uses `\tikz` syntax on p. 478, what does it mean? Is that syntax for Tex instead of Latex?

Comment: @ajeh `\tikz` is the the inline version of `tikzpicture` environment.